# Access ComboBoxes inside a ListView via C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, combobox

I have a ListView which contains 2 columns. The first column is a simple string. The second one's template is set to a single ComboBox. The amount of rows and respectively ComboBoxes is unknown.

My XAML:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" Name="listView" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding ImportColumns}">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <local:ListFilterMultiConverter x:Key="listFilterConverter" />
            </ListView.Resources>

            <ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">

                    <GridViewColumn Header="File column" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileColumnHeader}"/>

                    <GridViewColumn Header="Worksheet column">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>

                                <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center" DataContext="{Binding DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" SelectedIndex="0" >
                                    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource listFilterConverter}">
                                            <Binding Path="ListOfWorksheetColumns.UnselectedWorksheetColumns"/>
                                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                                </ComboBox>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>

        </ListView>
```

I need to know what is in a combobox in the second column, so that the string in the first column could be associated with a value of the respective ComboBox. The problem is that I have a reference only to the items in the first column.

My ImportColumn class:

```
public class ImportColumn : BaseViewModel
{
    public string FileColumnHeader { get; set; }
}
```

BaseViewModel class:

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (sender, e) => { };
}
```

Comment: Breaking the DataContext was a mistake. I'd advise you to lose that, and fix the first Binding in your MultiBinding for ItemsSource so that it uses the relativesource. I think that would be `<Binding Path="DataContext.ListOfWorksheetColumns.UnselectedWorksheetColumns" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}" />`. Then your DataContext in that CellTemplate will be the row item, an `ImportColumn` I suspect. Next, make `ImportColumn`'s properties raise PropertyChanged when their values change, and bind ComboBox.SelectedItem as needed.

Comment: `SelectedItem="{Binding FileColumnHeader}"` is what I think you want. There's certainly no need to resort to event handlers to do stuff like this in WPF.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thank you! This is the second time I got a quick and the right answer from you. I'm quite confused; what should I formally do about your answer, since it's a comment?

Comment: Glad to help. I've expanded the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a mistake to bind DataContext as you've done here, because that bound DataContext will be the default source for any other binding on the ComboBox. That gets in the way because you want to be able to bind to properties of the real datacontext, which is the row object, `ImportColumn`.

We can fix this by using the same RelativeSource you're using for the DataContext inside your multibinding, which leaves us free to bind ComboBox.SelectedItem to `FileColumnHeader` on the `ImportColumn` for that row.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ComboBox 
        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding FileColumnHeader}"
        SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"
        >
        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource listFilterConverter}">
                <Binding 
                    Path="DataContext.ListOfWorksheetColumns.UnselectedWorksheetColumns"
                    RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}"
                    />
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    </ComboBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

I've learned in comments that the SelectionChanged handler is being used for other stuff that can and arguably should be done in MVVM, but it gets a bit involved.

For that to work right, `ImportColumn.FileColumnHeader` needs to properly raise PropertyChanged when its value changes. Since you've got `ImportColumn` inheriting from something called `BaseViewModel`, I'm going to guess that you may have omitted that detail for the sake of brevity.

A bit off topic: I'm confident that your `listFilterConverter` should be taking something other than a `ComboBox` as its second parameter. Whatever properties it's getting from the ComboBox, you should be just binding those properties instead. A converter is much harder to reuse if the consumer needs to wrap its parameters in a `ComboBox`. But that's not of the essence right now.

Comment: Thank you, I had to declare a new property on ImportColumn to hold the selected item of a combobox, because "FileColumnHeader" is used in the first column of the listview. Also, I have improved my converter. As for SelectionChanged, ComboBoxes are filled with WorksheetColumn class items which have the "Selected" property. I had used SelectionChanged to set "Selected" property of previously chosen WorksheetColumn to false and set "Selected" to true for the newly chosen WorksheetColumn in the drop-down list.

Comment: @Quasimodo Ah, I see. You can definitely do that in pure MVVM, but it gets to be a lot of objects handling each others' propertychanged and collectionchanged events. I'll edit my answer to clarify what "stuff like this" meant -- basically, I meant "stuff like what the binding on ComboBox.SelectedItem is now doing".